# Search Box and Layer control on multiple layers folium Python

Tags: python, layer, folium

I want to add some markers to a map, and have a search box and a layer selection on them. In particular having the search box on some properties of the markers and the layer selection on other properties.

Here is the code I'm using. I've tried having multiple layers, one for each value of the property I want to use to select them, and then merging them into 1 unique layer. But then the search doesn't work.

[Here is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkKyt.png) As you can see, the layers work but the search can't find the marker.

```
    import folium
    from folium import features
    cl_type='Static_clustering'
    m = folium.Map([45.75345246,12.34117475], zoom_start=20)
    var = np.random.choice([-1,1],size=2)*np.clip(np.abs(np.random.normal(0.0005,scale = 0.0001,size=2)),10**(-6),10**(-4))
    points = {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
     'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
       'properties': {'Codice': 500732, 'Categoria': 'D1', 'Cluster': 3},
       'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [12.34117475, 45.75345246]},
       'id': '0'},
      {'type': 'Feature',
       'properties': {'Codice': 500735, 'Categoria': 'A2', 'Cluster': 2},
       'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [12.34127475, 45.75345246]},
       'id': '1'}]}
       
    gj = folium.GeoJson(points)
    feature_group_cl = {cl:folium.FeatureGroup('cluster '+str(cl)) for cl in [2,3]}
    tot_layer = folium.FeatureGroup('all')
    
    for feature in gj.data['features']:
        if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Point':
            marker = folium.Marker(location=list(reversed(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])),
                icon=folium.Icon(color='red'), Codice =feature['properties']['Codice'],
                popup='Hello'
            )
            #marker.add_to(m)
            marker.add_to(feature_group_cl[feature['properties']['Cluster']])
            
    for feat_group in feature_group_cl.values():
        feat_group.add_to(tot_layer)
        feat_group.add_to(m)
    tot_layer.add_to(m)
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
    
    Search(
        layer=tot_layer,
        search_label="Codice",
    ).add_to(m)
    
    
    m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your search box to a folium GeoJson object instead of a layer object. In order to only have one time the points on the map, yon can put the geojson data into another `folium.FeatureGroup` with the parameter `show=False`. You can modify the end of your code like this :

```
geo_layer = folium.FeatureGroup('geojson', show=False)
tot_layer.add_to(m)
geo_layer.add_to(m)
gj.add_to(geo_layer)
Search(
    layer=gj,
    search_label="Codice",
).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! Although in this way I saw that I'll double the points, and so the map becomes really heavy... Because the search will be on gj points, and the same points will be present also in tot_layer so that I can do the filter on the layers. Is there a way to have the search and the layering on only I replica of the points?

Comment: great thank you! Is there a way to specify different layer controls on the attributes of the marker rather then on a whole set of markers... as if it was more a filter than a layer control?